# Getting error -> Unexpected token }

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, syntax

I am getting the error as stated in the title.

Here is the html code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> PhoneGap </title>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.3.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="fileopener.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
         <h1>PDF Open Tester</h1>
         <a href="#" onclick="window.plugins.fileOpener.open("/sdcard/Course Content Files/1.pdf");">open</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the fileopener.js

```
function FileOpener() {
};

FileOpener.prototype.open = function(url) {
    cordova.exec(null, null, "FileOpener", "openFile", [url]);
};

if(!window.plugins) {
    window.plugins = {};
}
if (!window.plugins.fileOpener) {
    window.plugins.fileOpener = new FileOpener();
}
```

What is the error? My assumption is that the error is not in the cordova javascript file.

**Edit** From comments:

I'm also getting a further error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fileOpener' of undefined.
```

Comment: I can't spot an error. I think the error is somewhere else.

Comment: You need to escape the quotes in the `onclick` attribute, or use single quotes on the inner pair inside `.open('...')`

Comment: what other information do you need? You can refer to this question as it is somewhat related, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15203770/opening-pdf-files-on-phonegap.

Comment: How do I set Michael's answer as the right answer?

Comment: @VedaSadhak can't, its in a comment, ask him to put it as an official answer if you want to accept it/+1

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski please view the comment above.

Comment: Also if you have the time, Im also getting a further error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fileOpener' of undefined. I don't want to create a new question if someone here already knows what the problem is. Please help if you can I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: @VedaSadhak Where are you getting the TypeError? Has the fileopener.js file correctly loaded? The code in there initializing `window.plugins = {}` ought to work correctly.

Comment: Did you wait for the deviceready event?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski im getting the error at line 11 which is, <a href="#" onclick="window.plugins.fileOpener.open("/sdcard/Course Content Files/1.pdf")

Comment: @SimonMacDonald no I have not waited for device ready, implementing it now.

Comment: I found the error, I had - instead of = infront of the src in the header.....I feel so stupid.

Comment: @VedaSadhak Ok. I'll put my earlier comment as an answer then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Porting comment to answer at OP's request:

The quoting in the HTML markup is faulty.  The `onclick` attribute's outer quotes are double, but double quotes have also been used on a string inside the `.open()` method call.  Change one or the other to single quotes. Since you are already using double quotes for HTML attributes, probably it is best to use single inside the method call string.

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.plugins.fileOpener.open('/sdcard/Course Content Files/1.pdf');">open</a>
```

The best strategy would be to avoid placing the `onclick` inside the markup entirely, and instead bind the event in code using whatever method is appropriate for PhoneGap applications.